# Maintenance Page in aws Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, maintenance-mode

Created behavior in AWS cloud front like
**/api/* to Application load balancer**
**default (*) to S3**

want to route the traffic to maintenance page bucket during code deployment time, should allow to do smoke test from my static ip when set maintenance page.

How to archive this?

Answer (score 0):

- WAF - You can whitelist certain IP for smoke test and for the others IP present maintenance page.
- Lambda@Edge